Relationship between field $0$ and vector $\mathbf{0}$ in vector spaces
Given a vector space $V$ over a field $F$, consider the identity $0 \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$. Now, $0$ is also the absorbing element for field multiplication. But in terms of scalar multiplication, wouldn't it be incorrect to call it abosrbing element since $0 \in F$ and $\mathbf{0} \in V$ are in different sets? If so, what is the correct way to think about this relationship? Here $V$ does not have additional structure (inner products, other products, …), only the vector space axioms.
Your insight is much appreciated.

We just call it zero.

I guess that settles it

Absorbing element typically refers to a binary operation with both operands from the same set.  Scalar multiplication is not such a binary operation.

There is also the identity $c\mathbf{0}=\mathbf{0}$ (for all $c \in F$), in addition to the identity $0\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$ (for all $\mathbf{v} \in V$).
